# Gparted unable to resize partition

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I am trying to resize my 2.73 TiB partition but I am unable to do so. From what I've found, I will be unable to resize a partition that is in use so I have to boot from CD/USB.

There is the main problem, I am unable to do so! I changed some boot settings and manages to boot to a black screen and some beep sounds, so I will not be able to boot from a CD/USB.

Is there any alternatives to this or is there any ways to reset default boot options without entering BIOS? I believe I changed a setting where I boot from/with Windows options?? Problem is that I just tried my way forward because my computer was unable to find the USB with Windows 7, which I wanted to install.

[image]

Comment: Depends on the laptop. Most modern ones allow you to enter the boot menu without entering the BIOS with F9 or another FX. How did you install Ubuntu if you cannot start from USB/CD? I would try to solve that first and then resize it from the live system. Try a different version, it could be related to the video drivers.

Comment: My original OS was Windows 8.1 but then I switched over to Ubuntu 14.04 with USB.  Then I found out that a program I used is not compatible with ubuntu so I decided to switch to Windows 7. During this process my USB was undetectable for some reason, all 8 of them, even other OS's so I changed some settings in BIOS and got into this.

Comment: Have you tried restoring the factory settings of the BIOS?

Comment: katu how do I do that? When I boot up my PC it takes ~5 min to get into Ubuntu and it's all black screen, no "press F2 or del to enter BIOS" or anything!

Comment: Try using an external monitor in case your screen is broken.  If you don't have one, try Ctrl+Alt+F2 to open a console after Ubuntu has started. You should  see a login screen. The BIOS is normally F2 but it can also be the del button.

Comment: I got 2 screens, using a stationary PC.

Comment: You should be able to enter the BIOS without using any live USB. Unplug all USBs and press del when the computer turns on. Does it boot with the installed version of Ubuntu correctly?

Comment: From the picture, the sda3 partition contains a Logical Volume Manager 2 Physical Volume.  This is like a virtual hard drive that contains it's own partitions called LVM Logical Volumes.  You will need to resize the LVM LVs to free up space first before you will be able to resize the sda3 partition.  I highly recommend you read up on Logical Volume Management, and have a good backup before proceeding.